# What is % in the Haskell preprocessor and how does it relate to types like Uint8 (if at all)?

Tags: haskell, hsc2hs

I'd like to better understand the [following code](https://github.com/bmsherman/haskell-matlab/blob/4c57a51ccdb86a4747fb42b41e4bf5f4df1e023f/Foreign/Matlab/Array.hsc#L273-L306) in general.

The instances for `MDouble` are included in the snippet to demonstrate an example that doesn't use the preprocessor.

```hs
#let numarray t = "\
foreign import ccall unsafe mxIs%s :: MXArrayPtr -> IO CBool\n\
instance MXArrayComponent M%s where\n\
  isMXArray a = boolC =.< withMXArray a mxIs%s\n\
  createMXArray s = withNDims s (uncurry $ createNumericArray (mxClassOf (undefined :: M%s)) False) >>= mkMXArray\n\
  \
mxArrayGetOffset = arrayDataGet ;\
mxArraySetOffset = arrayDataSet ;\
mxArrayGetOffsetList = arrayDataGetList ;\
mxArraySetOffsetList = arrayDataSetList\
  \n\
instance MXArrayData MX%s M%s\
", #t, #t, #t, #t, #t, #t
foreign import ccall unsafe mxIsDouble :: MXArrayPtr -> IO CBool
foreign import ccall unsafe mxCreateDoubleScalar :: MXDouble -> IO MXArrayPtr
foreign import ccall unsafe mxGetScalar :: MXArrayPtr -> IO MXDouble
instance MXArrayComponent MDouble where
  isMXArray a = boolC =.< withMXArray a mxIsDouble
  createMXScalar = mxCreateDoubleScalar . hs2mx >=> mkMXArray
  mxScalarGet a = withMXArray a mxGetScalar
  createMXArray s = withNDims s (uncurry $ createNumericArray (mxClassOf (undefined :: Double)) False) >>= mkMXArray
  #arrayDataComponent
instance MXArrayData MXDouble MDouble
#numarray Single
#numarray Int8
#numarray Int16
#numarray Int32
#numarray Int64
#numarray Uint8
#numarray Uint16
#numarray Uint32
#numarray Uint64
```

But in particular, looks like they are using some types like `Uint8` etc., and I'm not sure where these are defined, or why e.g. `Word8` isn't used instead. Also, not sure how the `%s` is being used. I see a lot of references to `#` in the [hsc2hs docs](https://github.com/haskell/hsc2hs) but so far nothing about `%`.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: I can see why it appears that way, though as the answer shows, they are related in a very direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is bolded sentences in the linked docs:

> ```
> #let ⟨name⟩ ⟨parameters⟩ = "⟨definition⟩"
> ```
>
> Defines a macro to be applied to the Haskell source. Parameter names are comma-separated, not inside parens. Such macro is invoked as other #-constructs, starting with #name. **The definition will be put in the C program inside parens as arguments of printf.** To refer to a parameter, close the quote, put a parameter name and open the quote again, to let C string literals concatenate. **Or use printf's format directives.** Values of arguments must be given as strings, unless the macro stringifies them itself using the C preprocessor's #parameter syntax.

`%s` specifies a string parameter in `printf` (and you can see a fuller explanation e.g. [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html)).

So there's no `Uint8` type involved; it's just a string and when you substitute it into `numarray` you get

```
foreign import ccall unsafe mxIsUint8 :: MXArrayPtr -> IO CBool
instance MXArrayComponent MUint8 where
  ...
```

and this type is documented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/matlab-0.2.0.0/docs/Foreign-Matlab-Types.html):

```
type MUint8 = Word8
```